# What’s the actual difference between “among” and “between”?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice, american-english

Well, the thing is that I know that among is used to establish a relationship with 3 or more objects. On the other hand, between is just for two objects. Nevertheless, I do not understand what to write when it comes to some expressions.

Let’s say, for instance, that I want to emphasize a video game, in this case Doom, from other video games during the same era. How should I write the next sentence?

> A) I will emphasize the difference between Doom and other games from the same era.

or like this

> B) I will emphasize the difference among Doom and other games of the same era.

Since ”other games” are already more than two, or in this case, one object, shouldn’t it be among?

Furthermore, if I try to emphasize the difference among 3 objects, how should I write it?
Here I will explain the difference between Roses, Violets, and fruits. 
Or 
Here I will explain the difference among Roses, Violets, and fruits.

Thank you.

Comment: [There's a great answer to this question on ELU.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37636/between-vs-among)

Answer (score 3):

In your example you consider that you have to decide how many games are there: Doom + a number >=2.

However, from my point of view, you took the wrong path: you actually need to compare 2 **groups**:

- group 1: Doom (1 element);
- group 2: other games (2 or more).

From this point of view, "between" is the best choice:

> A) I will emphasize the difference between Doom and other games from the same era.

as in:

- Doom on one hand;

and

- other games, on the other hand.

Answer (score 1):

"between is just for two objects" This is not quite correct. "Between" can indeed be used for just two objects.(or groups) But it can also be used for  sets being compared in pairs. For example:

> There is a significant difference between parents and children.

This can be thought of as a comparison of two groups, or as a pairwise comparison of each parent with a corresponding child.

> - There is agreement between nouns and their pronouns.
> - There is a bond between mothers and daughters.

Here the comparison is clearly a pairwise one, each noun with a corresponding pronoun, each mother and her daughter.

---

As to the heart of the original question, I agree with the answer by virolino: the comparison should be of two **groups** of games, Doom and all others, giving

> I will emphasize the difference between Doom and other games from the same era.